# How can I disable terminal-polling for cpan used from crontab?

Tags: perl, cpan

I'd like to have all the installed CPAN modules updated automatically every night, so I've placed the following command in the `crontab`:

```
@daily cpan -i $(cpanp -o | perl -lane 'print $F[3]')
```

However, whenever this is run I get the following error message:

```
Unable to get Terminal Size. The TIOCGWINSZ ioctl didn't work. The COLUMNS and
LINES environment variables didn't work. The resize program didn't work. at
/usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Term/ReadKey.pm
line 362.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Term/ReadLine
/Perl.pm line 63.
```

What can I do to get this working?

Answer (score 3):

Come back on Monday. I'll add a `-u` command to `cpan` to do that if you promise to test it for me. You'll have to get the latest `cpan` from [App::Cpan](http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-Cpan).

Okay, don't wait until Monday. I've pushed the change to the [cpan-script Github repo](http://github.com/briandfoy/cpan-script), and [App-Cpan](http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-Cpan) 1.56_15 is on its way to CPAN.

Let me know if you have any problems or the new feature doesn't do what you want.

Comment: So to install this I only need to download http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/B/BD/BDFOY/App-Cpan-1.56_15.tar.gz and do the usual perl Makefile.PL etc. thing?

Answer (score 2):

**Please use *brian d foy's* answer as he added a cpan option to do this**

Are you trying to update the list of modules with CPAN or actually update any out of date modules (d/l, compile, install)?  This could be dangerous as modules could change interface and existing scripts would fail.  This error is due to CPAN trying to use Term::ReadLine and Term::ReadKey to interrogate the terminal.

If you really want to upgrade all your modules, you can use this command:

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'CPAN::Shell->install(CPAN::Shell->r)'
```

This is a small change from the command given in the documentation to interrogate CPAN for all outdated modules:

https://metacpan.org/pod/CPAN#PROGRAMMERS-INTERFACE

Comment: So what are the differences between using your command and the one I originally am using?

Comment: It calls a method that is part of the Install shell instead of loading the shell and running the command.

Answer (score 0):

> The COLUMNS and LINES environment variables didn't work.

Try setting the `COLUMNS` and `LINES` environment variables.

```
COLUMNS=80
LINES=24
@daily cpan -i $(cpanp -o | perl -lane 'print $F[3]')
```